# _.findwhere is not working when object has value as a array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

**_.findwhere** is always returing me **undefined** when I am using it for searching object who has value as a Array.

```
var nameArray = [{name:'firstName',value : ['Amruta','Swapnil']},{name:'LastName',value : ['Pawar','shaikh']}]

var element = _.findWhere(nameArray,{value:'Amruta'});

console.log("element is " + element);
```

I am getting value of element as a undefiend instead of value..

Answer (score 3):

`findWhere` is used to find items by their property where it is an exact match. In your case, you are trying to find the item whose `value` property includes a specific text. You can do it by passing a predicate to the `find` as second argument:

```js
var nameArray = [{name:'firstName',value : ['Amruta','Swapnil']},{name:'LastName',value : ['Pawar','shaikh']}]

var element = _.find(nameArray,function(x){
    return x.value.includes("Amruta")
});

console.log(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @VitthalRudrawar Sorry that I made a mistake in my previous code. Use `find` instead of `findWhere`.

Comment: Also to make sure it is compatible with older browsers, you might want to include this polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control

Comment: I am using this function on backend so it will not break .. Thanks for updating

Comment: Hi Gökhan Kurt, This always returning me the first object irrespective of the check....Can you please check that once